# c++ 98, vector, remove every element except the first one

Tags: c++, c++98

Arr! This is how I do it, but it's kinda long. Anything more compact? (I am using cpp 98!)

```
std::vector<Object> allObjs;

// ... allObjs gets filled ...

// Now get back a vector with only the first element in allObjs
std::vector<Object> justTheFirstElemOfObjs;
justTheFirstElemOfObjs.push_back(allObjs.front());

allObjs = justTheFirstElemOfObjs;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`allObjs.resize(1);` should do the trick.